# How can this complex query be simplified?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a media center website that I'm working on that has a page that displays media categories.  Each category can have multiple media items assigned to it, and each media item can be assigned to multiple categories.

The page contains a text input that must be able to filter the categories that are shown.

What I need to be able to do is get every category that is associated with the current user (`$user_id`) as well as a media item belonging to that user (unused categories are not displayed).  Normally that would be simple enough, but I also have to be able to filter the categories based on fields in other tables associated with the media.

The fields I need to be able to apply the text filter to are as follows:

- `message_number` in the `media` table
- `keywords` in the `media` table
- `speaker_name` in the `media_speakers` table
- `series_name` in the `media_series` table
- `book_name` in the `media_books` table
- `category_name` in the `media_categories` table

As it is now, the query takes several seconds to complete.  I'm not a MySQL pro, so I'm sure there must be better ways to do what I need to do here.  In case it helps, I'm using MySQLi via PHP.  My query has several subqueries, which I'm positive is the cause of the problem, but I didn't know any other way to do what I'm trying to do.

Below are the relevant table structures and the current query.  I've included as much info as I can think of that can help someone to help me with this, but if you need more info please just let me know.

The `media` table (omitting some irrelevant fields) (series,speaker, and book fields contain the ID of a record in their corresponding tables):

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `message_number` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `series` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
  `speaker` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
  `book` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
  `keywords` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

The `media_series` table:

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `series_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cover` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

The `media_speakers` table:

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speaker_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cover` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

The `media_books` table:

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `book_shortname` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

The `media_categories` table:

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cover` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
```

The `media_categories_assoc` table:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_id` int(10) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `marked_for_deletion` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Finally, the over-complicated query:

```
 SELECT media_categories.id            `media_categories.id`,
       media_categories.user_id       `media_categories.user_id`,
       media_categories.category_name `media_categories.category_name`,
       media_categories.cover         `media_categories.cover`,
       (SELECT id
        FROM   media
        WHERE  user_id = '$user_id'
               AND media_categories.id IN (SELECT category_id
                                           FROM   media_category_assoc
                                           WHERE  user_id = '$user_id')
        ORDER  BY `date` DESC
        LIMIT  1)                     `media.id`,
       (SELECT `date`
        FROM   media
        WHERE  user_id = '$user_id'
               AND media_categories.id IN (SELECT category_id
                                           FROM   media_category_assoc
                                           WHERE  user_id = '$user_id')
        ORDER  BY `date` DESC
        LIMIT  1)                     `media.date`,
       (SELECT series
        FROM   media
        WHERE  user_id = '$user_id'
               AND media_categories.id IN (SELECT category_id
                                           FROM   media_category_assoc
                                           WHERE  user_id = '$user_id')
        ORDER  BY `date` DESC
        LIMIT  1)                     `media.series`,
       (SELECT speaker
        FROM   media
        WHERE  user_id = '$user_id'
               AND media_categories.id IN (SELECT category_id
                                           FROM   media_category_assoc
                                           WHERE  user_id = '$user_id')
        ORDER  BY `date` DESC
        LIMIT  1)                     `media.speaker`
FROM   media_categories
       LEFT JOIN media
              ON media.id IN (SELECT media_id
                              FROM   media_category_assoc
                              WHERE  media_id = media.id
                                     AND user_id = '$user_id')
       LEFT JOIN media_series
              ON media.series = media_series.id
       LEFT JOIN media_speakers
              ON media.speaker = media_speakers.id
       LEFT JOIN media_books
              ON media.book = media_books.id
WHERE  media_categories.user_id = '$user_id'
       AND media_categories.id IN (SELECT category_id
                                   FROM   media_category_assoc
                                   WHERE  user_id = '$user_id')
       AND ( media.title LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media.message_number LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media.keywords LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_speakers.speaker_name LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_categories.category_name LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_series.series_name LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_books.book_name LIKE '%filter_text%' )
GROUP  BY `media_categories.id`
ORDER  BY `media.date` DESC
LIMIT  0, 12;
```

Comment: Subqueries indeed may be causing your query to be so slow. Try a "divide-and-conquer" approach: Create temporary tables for the "intermediate" steps (subqueries) and then put them together... You can put all the creation of temporary tables in a stored procedure, wich will help you define each query parameters only once. Be sure to create all the needed indexes in each temp table.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for the tip.  Temporary tables does sound like it might be helpful.  However I'm not really quite sure how I would implement that here, and I'm not sure what you mean by 'needed indexes'.

Comment: How is my question off topic??

Comment: Don't worry to much about it, @vertigo - everyone gets a close from time to time. FWIW, questions here should be as generalised as possible, so it is possible people should have closed as Too Localised, but categorised it wrongly. That said, it looks like it is going to reopen. Bear in mind here that a "close" on Stack Overflow isn't as final as it sounds - where you get one of those, ask calmly for clarification (I agree it would be useful here) and someone hopefully will provide it.

Comment: @halfer, thank you.  I always try to do my best to make sure that content I post on forums or support sites falls within the proper guidelines, and it's particularly frustrating when my posts are marked as not following guidelines but without offering any explanation.  If there is really something wrong with my post, I need to know what it is so I can possibly avoid it in the future.

Comment: @vertigo: indeed. If you get such issues in future, feel free to post on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Your description doesn't mention anything about requiring the most recent data, but clearly that's where your query's heading. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Strawberry, I guess I failed to mention that because I actually want ALL of the data associated with each category, regardless of date.  However, I do think i need to have it output to the page starting with the most recent at top.  If multiple categories contain the same media item, which will happen, then the order amongst those doesn't matter.  For example, if the most recently added media has 3 categories associated with it, as long as those three are shown first, the order of those three amongst themselves doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you should start again. Try to express your query in the simplest terms possible, with (at least initially) no subqueries. Then gradually build in complexity. Also your surrogate PK in the assoc table seems to serve no purpose. I suggest you replace it with some combination of the 3 succeeding columns. Oh, and calling an alias  `media.id` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Strawberry, yeah, you're probably right.  I should probably just start with a new query.  Part of the problem here is that this was originally a query used for a different page that wasn't as complex.  It was copied and modified a few times before being copied once again to be used for the 'Categories' page, where it became this complex.  When I first tested it, it worked okay because I had hardly any categories.  After creating several, I noticed it was quite slow.  I will start the query over today.

Comment: Actually I just had an idea.  The only reason I need to have those subqueries is because I need to be able to filter the results based on a fields in other tables... what if I performed the filter first in a different query, and then performed the main output query based only on the results from the first?  I can try that...

Comment: No. That might work, but it's not a great idea. As a general rule, it's best to reduce round trips to the database to a minimum.

Comment: Well, I just implemented my idea and it's working like a charm!  In fact, now it loads even faster than the other pages, and I'm considering using the same method for those as well.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, the subqueries can be the bottlenecks in your query. First of all, run an `explain select...` on your query to check the execution plan.

See the reference manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Now, about the suggestion I made about using temporary tables, I'll take your first subquery to make an example.

You use this:

```sql
SELECT 
...,
(SELECT id
    FROM   media
    WHERE  user_id = '$user_id'
           AND media_categories.id IN (SELECT category_id
                                       FROM   media_category_assoc
                                       WHERE  user_id = '$user_id')
    ORDER  BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT  1),
....
```

And you can do something like this:

```sql
drop table if exists temp_step1;
create temporary table temp_step1
    select id
    from media
    where user_id = @user_id -- I'm assuming you are putting this in a stored procedure
        and media_categories.id in (SELECT category_id 
                                    FROM media_category_assoc
                                    WHERE  user_id = @user_id)
    order by `date` desc
    limit 1;
```

Then you can use this `temp_step1` table as a row source for your big query.

Notice that this example returns only one row, so there's no point on indexing this. For those temp tables that contain more than one row and which you use in the `FROM ... JOIN ...` clause of your query, you will need to create indexes *at the very least* on all the fields you are doing the joins. To do that, after creating the temp table (for example `temp_step_X`) you should do this:

```sql
alter table temp_step_X
   add index idx_indexName(field1),
   ...;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to explain this.  I will see if I can implement this into my code later after my brain has rested.  Thanks for getting this answer in before my question was unjustly closed as being "off topic".

Comment: @vertigoelectric Your question might be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com Be adviced: cross-posting is discouraged (i.e. posting the same question on different stackexchange sites)

Comment: Cross posting's fine as long as you let everyone know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If I have been able to understand the query correctly you try to get some extra information from the most recent media per category for a given user. As far as I can see all of the subqueries in the SELECT-clause can then be moved to the FROM-clause.

Maybe doing it like this could help ?

```
SELECT media_categories.id,
       media_categories.user_id,
       media_categories.category_name,
       media_categories.cover,
       newest_media.id,
       newest_media.'date',
       newest_media.series,
       newest_media.speaker
FROM   media_categories
        LEFT JOIN media_category_assoc
              ON media_categories.id = media_category_assoc.category_id AND media_categories.user_id = media_category_assoc.user_id
        LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT id, 'date', series, speaker
                    FROM   media
                    WHERE  media.id = media_category_assoc.media_id
                    ORDER  BY `date` DESC
                    LIMIT  1
                ) newest_media ON newest_media.user_id = '$user_id'
       LEFT JOIN media_series
              ON newest_media.series = media_series.id
       LEFT JOIN media_speakers
              ON newest_media.speaker = media_speakers.id
       LEFT JOIN media_books
              ON newest_media.book = media_books.id
       LEFT JOIN media
              ON media.id = media_category_assoc.media_id AND media.user_id = '$user_id'
WHERE  media_categories.user_id = '$user_id'
       AND ( media.title LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media.message_number LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media.keywords LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_speakers.speaker_name LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_categories.category_name LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_series.series_name LIKE '%filter_text%'
              OR media_books.book_name LIKE '%filter_text%' )
GROUP  BY `media_categories.id`
ORDER  BY `media.date` DESC
LIMIT  0, 12;
```